# How to make an auto-hide the JToolBar?

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I'd like to make an auto-hide the `JToolBar` and it appear only when the mouse goes near/over the `JToolBar`. I have added the `JToolBar` in `JPanel`. There is no mouseover listener in `JToolBar`. How to do this?

Comment: can you please post SSCCE maybe there no needed apply the `MouseWhatever`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `MouseMotionListener` to your `JFrame` or `JDialog`.

```
addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
         toolbar.setVisible(e.getY() < 10);
     }
});
```

In that way, the tool bar will only be shown if the mouse is in the top 10 vertical pixels of the window.

Answer (score 3):

> There is no mouseover listener in JToolBar

You would use a `MouseListener` is handle the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events.

But you will have a problem because the mouse events will only be passed to a visible component. So once you hide the toolbar is will not receive the mouseEntered event.

So I don't understand your design. Do you plan to have the other components shift up to fill the space by the toolbar? Or will you just leave the space empty? In the latter case you would then need to add the MouseMotionListener to the panel and handle the mouseMoved event to see the the mouse is at a location where the toolbar should be.

Comment: +1 `because the mouse events will only be passed to a visible component`,